# problem with a string's format in c++ while doing tcp communication

Tags: c++

i am building a simple c++ client, i am splitting the info i get from the server to frames, and pass each frame to a function that processes it, i split the frame into lines using

```
Poco::StringTokenizer tokenizer(frame, "\n");
```

i take the first line of the tokenizer which represents the type of frame

```
 StmpCommand command(tokenizer[0]);
```

a StmpCommand is an enum with the different types of messages
and the constructor works as follows :

```
StmpCommand(std::string command): commandType_() {
  bool x=command=="CONNECTED";
  std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
  if ("SUBSCRIBE" == command)
   commandType_ =  SUBSCRIBE;
  else if ("UNSUBSCRIBE" == command)
   commandType_ =  UNSUBSCRIBE;
  else if ("SEND" == command)
   commandType_ =  SEND;
  else if ("BEGIN" == command)
   commandType_ =  BEGIN;
  else if ("COMMIT" == command)
   commandType_ =  COMMIT;
  else if ("CONNECT" == command)
   commandType_ =  CONNECT;
  else if ("MESSAGE" == command)
   commandType_ =  MESSAGE;
  else if ("RECEIPT" == command)
   commandType_ =  RECEIPT;
  else if ("CONNECTED" == command)
   commandType_ =  CONNECTED;
  else if ("DISCONNECT" == command)
   commandType_ =  DISCONNECT;
  else if ("ERROR" == command)
   commandType_ =  ERROR;
  else {
   std::cerr<<"Error in building StmpCommand object, unknown type - "<<command<<std::endl;
  }
 }
```

the first frame i am trying to proccess is a CONNECTED frame
therefor i try to create a StmpCommand with CONNECTED as the constructor's only argument
and for some reason i am getting an :

```
Error in building StmpCommand object, unknown type - �CONNECTED
```

i am clearly passing a string containing CONNECTED but i'm guessing there is something else there that isn't allowing the condition else if ("CONNECTED" == command) to hap

Comment: My wild guess is server might be sending \r\n instead of just \n.

Comment: If StmpCommand actually means SMTP, then yeah, it's definitely using `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: it actually means STOMP protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a stray character at the start of the command. "�CONNECTED" shows as a CONNECTED here, meaning there is one non-displayable character in there at least.

Comment: printing command.length(), i get 10 characters, so i'm definitely getting an extra char